# Send payment gateway response to requestb.in

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed a custom payment gateway plugin,currently i works find but i still need to capture the response from the gateway to requestb URL.

I have managed to send the respond via wp_mail,

```
if (isset($_GET['wc-api']) && $_GET['wc-api'] == 'woocommerce_mpay') {
    wp_mail('email@gmail.com','API Response', json_encode($_GET['result']));
    /** need to trim from result **/
    $Url_result = $_GET['result'];

    $order = new WC_Order( (int) substr($Url_result,7,20) );

    $tranID = (int)substr($Url_result,1,6);



    if (substr($Url_result,0,1) == '0'){

        $r_status = 0;

    }else{

    $r_status = 33;

    }
```

But still i want it to be on requestbin url.